# espeak returns error on ubuntu server

Tags: server, pulseaudio, alsa

I want to use espeak on my server, so I can scare my girlfriend from work :)

ubuntu 11.04 server.

```
sudo espeak -v en "Hello i am espeak"
```

Error:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2212:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2212:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2212:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Answer (score 3):

even if you are using the ubuntu server install, you might have the [pulseaudio](/questions/tagged/pulseaudio) sound server running. This will default to surround alsa emulation which espeak isn't capable to handle.

Use: `espeak -v en "Hello i am espeak" --stdout|paplay` instead.

Comment: I get "The program 'paplay' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils"

Comment: Then just do so.

Comment: I get a `pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused` error message when I do this.

Answer (score 1):

I had exakt the same problem on a Raspberry Pi.
For me it worked fine with:

```
espeak -v en "Hello i am espeak" --stdout | aplay
```

(aplay instead of paplay)